# Getting Uninstall string for application from regedit via powershell

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, text-parsing, uninstallstring

I have been getting the  uninstall string via below script.

But I am getting an output like this.

```
MsiExec.exe /I{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}
```

My desired output:

```
{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}
```

After desired output , I will assign this value to the variable such as $uninstallString. And I will use it inside my doRemoveMSI function like below.

```
$paths = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
Get-ChildItem $paths |
    Where-Object{ $_.GetValue('DisplayName') -match 'APP' } | 
    ForEach-Object{ 
        $uninstallString = $_.GetValue('UninstallString')
       
        $uninstallString
    }


doRemoveMSI -msi "msiexec.exe" -arguments '/x', '$uninstallString', '/quiet', 'REBOOT=R', '/L*V "C:\msilog.log"'
```

Comment: TRy following :  "MsiExec.exe /I{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}" -match "\{(?<id>[^}]+)"
 Write-Host $Matches["id"]

Comment: `get-package *app* | uninstall-package`

Comment: Invoke-Expression (get-package *$app* -ErrorAction ignore).meta.Attributes["UninstallString"] (warning, this will delete the app).

Comment: @rinatgadeev, this isn't robust, because such command lines aren't written with _PowerShell_ syntax in mind, which causes problems, notably with unquoted `{...}` arguments; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375).

Answer (score 0):

As an aside:

- If you're using *Windows PowerShell* and only need to remove *MSI-installed* applications, a much more convenient solution is to use [`Uninstall-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/uninstall-package), as [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) points out; e.g., 
  `Get-Package -ProviderName msi *App* | Uninstall-Package`
- If you're looking to execute `UninstallString` / `QuietUninstallString` command lines extracted from the registry *as-is*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382753/45375).

---

Your question can be reduced to **how to extract a `{...}` substring from a larger string**, which you can do with PowerShell's [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```bash
# -> '{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}'
'MsiExec.exe /I{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}' -replace '^.+({.+?}).*$', '$1'
```

<sup>Note: `{` and `}` are *situationally* regex metacharacters, but are treated literally here, because they aren't part of valid quantifier subexpressions (such as `o{2,3}`). You may choose to *always* escape them as `\{` and `\}`, to be safe.</sup>

Alternatively, you could use the equally regex-based [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator, and split the string into tokens by `{` and `}`, including those separators, with the help of look-around assertions, and extracting the 2nd token (`[1]`):

```bash
# -> '{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}'
('MsiExec.exe /I{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}' -split '(?={)|(?<=})')[1]
```

<sup>See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/1e8Jtb/1) for a detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it. Note that the look-around assertions only match character *positions*, not actual characters, which is what enables including `{` and `}` in the tokens returned by `-split`.</sup>

Or the `.Split()` *method* of the .NET `[string]` type, passing an *array* of (literal) characters to split by, using an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) with the `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) to surround the extracted token in `{` and `}` again.

```bash
# -> '{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}'
"{$( ('MsiExec.exe /I{629388F2-A011-4F5C-A6BF-98A80A25317C}').Split([char[]] '{}')[1] )}"
```

---

**Speaking of *expandable strings*:**

The `'$uninstallString'` in your `doRemoveMSI` call,

> ```bash
> doRemoveMSI -msi "msiexec.exe" -arguments '/x', '$uninstallString', '/quiet', 'REBOOT=R', '/L*V "C:\msilog.log"'
> ```

won't work as intended, because *NO* expansion (string interpolation) happens inside `'...'`, i.e. [*verbatim* (single-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings).

While `"$uninstallString"` avoids that problem, you do not even need the `"..."` (except in cases where you need explicit *to-string conversion*), and can simply pass `$uninstallString` as-is.

---

**As for how you're *partitioning* the arguments you're passing to `doRemoveMSI`** (consider renaming the function to conform to PowerShell's naming conventions, e.g., `Uninstall-Msi`):

- As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75561592/45375) to your previous question, given your desire to pass argument *pairs* via a *single string* with *embedded double-quoting* - e.g. `'/L*V "C:\msilog.log"'` - it is ultimately simpler to pass a *single string overall*, i.e. to declare your `-arguments` parameter as type `[string]`, and then invoke the function as follows:

```bash
# Note the use of a *single* "..." string, 
# with *embeded* " chars. escaped as `"
doRemoveMSI -msi msiexec.exe -arguments "/x $uninstallString /quiet REBOOT=R /L*V `"C:\msilog.log`""
```